# Navicat carriage return in results

Tags: oracle, navicat

I am running a query on my database with Navicat and I am using the ORDER BY CASE to print out the results in a specific order. I would like to insert a carriage return between each result, but I am not finding any information on how to do that. Ideally, I would like to have a record returned, a blank row of cells, then the next record printed below that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this tool but assuming you have multiple rows from the query, then this is a display issue I would think.  You need to provide more details, like the query, output, etc.

Comment: If you're talking about a row of cells in an output grid then that would be tricky; and seems odd anyway. A carriage return in a row of data is a different issue, but might not appear (SQL Developer wouldn't show it in its result grid I think), and also seems odd. If you're producing nicely formatted output then perhaps put the results in a word processing and increase line spacing? Otherwise it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, or why.

Answer (score 0):

Probably as many other community members, I don't use Navicat. I Googled for it - looks like GUI tools I've seen (SQL Developer, TOAD) with nice features. I doubt it is capable of doing what you want *out of the box*.

You didn't say what you plan to do with such an output - maybe spool it into a (CSV?) file? If so, there's a workaround: use SQL*Plus whose `SET RECSEP` setting does exactly that, with no effort at all.

This is default:

```
SQL> select * from dept order by dname, loc;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
```

Setting I mentioned:

```
SQL> set recsep each
SQL> select * from dept order by dname, loc;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK

        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS

        30 SALES          CHICAGO


SQL>
```

Cool, isn't it?

---

Otherwise, a workaround that doesn't exactly add carriage return, but adds empty rows. To do that, I used several CTEs:

- `your_query` is your (my) current query with two additional columns:

  - `rn` which returns row number, sorted by column(s) you want
  - `cnt` which returns total number of rows returned by your query
- `counter` is a row generator, generating as many rows as your query returns (in my example, my query returned 4 rows; `counter` creates 4 rows as well)
- `temp` unions these two queries:

  - your query is trivial
  - it is unioned with query that returns `rn` from counter, while other columns are `null`. Visually, it'll return result you wanted (empty rows)
- finally, select only significant columns sorted by `rn`

---

```
SQL> with
  2  your_query as
  3    (select deptno, dname, loc,
  4       --
  5       row_number() over (order by dname, loc) rn,
  6       count(*) over () cnt
  7     from dept
  8    ),
  9  counter as
 10    (select level rn
 11     from dual
 12     connect by level <= (select cnt
 13                          from your_query
 14                          where rownum = 1
 15                         )
 16    ),
 17  temp as
 18    (select a.rn, a.deptno, a.dname, a.loc
 19     from your_query a
 20     union all
 21     select b.rn, null, null, null
 22     from counter b
 23    )
 24  select deptno, dname, loc
 25  from temp
 26  order by rn, deptno;
```

Result:

```
    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK

        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS

        30 SALES          CHICAGO


8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

If you wonder how it looks in GUI, here it is (from SQL Developer):

[image]